# Subgroups of a group of order 60 with a normal subgroup of order 2 (Sylow)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

This is the problem 38 of the chapter 24 in the Gallian's Algebra.

> Suppose that $G$ is a group of order $60$ and $G$ has a normal
>   subgroup $N$ of order $2$. Show that:
>
> 1. $G$ has normal subgroups of order 6, 10, 30.
> 2. $G$ has subgroups of order 12 and 20.
> 3. $G$ has a ciclic subgroup of order 30.

I've been dealing with this problem, but it seems i don't have good ideas. I could only prove the first item for the order 30.

Can someone give me a hand please? Thanks!

Comment: I am almost certain that the way you do this is look at the group $G/N$. Use the fact $|G/N| = 30$, and see what the Sylow theorems tell you about which subgroups of $G/N$ have to exist. Then pull those subgroups back through the homomorphism $f:G \rightarrow G/N$. Those will be the subgroups you want.

Side note: How did you prove the first item for order 30?

Comment: @coolpapa That looks like most of an answer to me.

Comment: @coolpapa. I did it this way: Consider the group $G/N$, one can prove that a Sylow 3-subgroup of it is normal or a Sylow 5-subgroup of it is normal, then we create a subgroup of $G/N$ of order 15 that has the form $A/N$ with $A\leq G$, then $|A|=30$ and as $|G:A|=2$, it is normal.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that $G$ has a subgroup of any order which divides 60?

Comment: @Alfred Yerger, I don't think so, i think that $A_{5}$ doesn't satisfy that.

Comment: Well, but $A_{5}$ also doesn't have a normal subgroup of order 2, so it's not part of this question.

Comment: Uhmm You're right. Do you think that is true?

Comment: Such a group $G$ will have a subgroup of any order, but it's deducable from this problem - I'm not sure how one would prove it directly other than using this as an outline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've got it. Order 30 is tricky. As in Devilathor's comment, create a subgroup $H$ of $G/N$ with order 15. Then $H$ is normal in $G/N$. However, since $|H| = 15$, it must have a normal Sylow 5-subgroup no matter what. Now the trickier bit - $|H| \cong \mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Since $P_{3}$ normalizes $P_{5}$, it must act on $P_{5}$ by conjugation. However, $P_{3} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, which can only act trivially on $P_{5}$, since $|\textrm{Aut}(P_{5})| = 4$. So $P_{3}$ and $P_{5}$ commute, and $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_{15}$. (That's as far as we can go with $H$, since it might be $D_{30}$, whose Sylow 2-subgroup is not normal.)

Now, we have normal 3- and 5-subgroups of $H$, which are actually characteristic in $H$, so they're normal in $G/N$ as well. That means when we pull them upstairs to $G$, they're normal in $G$. That gives us our normal subgroups for part 1.

For part 2, we pull a similar trick - the normal subgroup of order 6 has a characteristic Sylow 3-subgroup, so we have $Q_{3}$, a normal Sylow 3-subgroup of $G$ - multiply that by a Sylow 2-subgroup and you get a subgroup of order 12. Then do the same with the normal subgroup of size 10 and $p=5$.

For part 3, just multiply together $Q_{3}$, $Q_{5}$, and $N$. Those are normal subgroups of $G$ that don't intersect, so they commute and their product is Abelian.

Comment: Hi coolpapa, thanks for your answer, it's brilliant.

I think I've found a simple way to do it, but i have not checked it out.

Comment: We know about the existence of the subgroup $A$ of $G$ order 30, well, this subgroup will contain a subgroup of order $15$ $B$(which is cyclic) and as $N\subseteq A$, we'll have that $A=B\times N$ and therefore $A$ is abelian.

The point here is that $A$ will contain all the Sylow 3-subgroups of $G$ (and the Sylow 5-subgroups as well) and $A$ contains only one subgroup of order 3, this subgroup will allow us to build the required groups.

Again, thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Ah, right. Once you have the subgroup of order 30, just reconstruct our group of order 15 in $G$ and go from there.